# Why parts of my app working with one context and don't work with another?

Tags: android, android-context

Ok, i have a class `LibApp` ,it's extended Application class and store Context:

```
public class LibApp extends Application {
    private static LibApp instance;
    private static Context context;

    private AppModule appModule;
    private AppComponent appComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ...
        instance = this;
        context = getApplicationContext();
        ...
    }

    public static LibApp getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then i have Activity with Fragment, and this Fragment contain RecyclerView and Adapter to it. My adapter called `HomePacksAdapter` and he heed Context to create ImageView. So, if i write:

```
HomePacksAdapter adapter = new HomePacksAdapter(getContext());
```

All works correct. But if i write:

```
HomePacksAdapter adapter = new HomePacksAdapter(LibApp.getContext());
```

I'm crushing with:

`android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

I don't think i understand what the Context is, because i can't explain why one Context "better" that another one. In my definition Context is object which provide app basic functions, so what, app Context don't provide those things that my adapter needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getApplicationContext()` - Returns the context for all activities running in application. So your home adapter needs just the context of your activity to inflate views whereas you are providing the context of all activities so it simply couldn't determine where to inflate views.

`getBaseContext()` - If you want to access Context from another context within application you can access.

`getContext()` - Returns the context view of only current running activity, which indeed is the reason it works fine when you use the getContext() as it finds the context of activity to inflate views.

Hope it helps.